# Django - Cannot 'migrate'

Tags: python, django, apache, migrate

I am currently trying to deploy my new changes to my raspberry-pi (while virtualenv is activated), but with I run `python manage.py migrate` I receive the error below:

`Applying CloudRoni.0007_auto_20180129_2007...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/pi/CloudRoni/cloudronienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/pi/CloudRoni/cloudronienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/pi/CloudRoni/cloudronienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/pi/CloudRoni/cloudronienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/pi/CloudRoni/cloudronienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/pi/CloudRoni/cloudronienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/pi/CloudRoni/cloudronienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/pi/CloudRoni/cloudronienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/pi/CloudRoni/cloudronienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/pi/CloudRoni/cloudronienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 97, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/home/pi/CloudRoni/cloudronienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 303, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/home/pi/CloudRoni/cloudronienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 120, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/pi/CloudRoni/cloudronienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/pi/CloudRoni/cloudronienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/pi/CloudRoni/cloudronienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/pi/CloudRoni/cloudronienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 63, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/pi/CloudRoni/cloudronienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 326, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file`

When I try to run `sudo python manage.py migrate` I receive:

`File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?`

I have ran migrations before and it has been awhile since I have deployed, but nothing has changed and any troubleshooting help is appreciated.

Edit: Include that my virtualenv is activated

Comment: It turns out I had changed the owner of the main directory and all I had to do was grant permissions back. User error basically...

Answer (score 0):

It's showing Django is not installed, you are possibly getting the error because you have not activated virtual environment.
Go to the particular folder where virtual environment exists and try-

```
source myvenv/bin/activate
```

replace '**myvenv**' with your virtual environment name and try to migrate.

Comment: I should have put this but my virtualenv is activated

Comment: Is it also activated as part of the `sudo` environment?

Comment: It is not, but if I try `sudo source <myvenv>/bin/activate` I receive the error `sudo: source: command not found`